# How to find a text in a field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem that I can get a data from mongoDB but it's not what i want.

I just want to get a data, if datas have "#l" sting in the message field, I want it.

here's data on mongodb

```
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #lol blah blah blah hellohellohellohello'})
({...someData, message: '#lol asdfff blah blah blah byebyebye'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff asdffasfdah blah blah #lol hello'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #l blah blah blah hello'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #lo blah blah blah hello'})
```

here's what i've done

```
export const getHashtagPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const { hashtag } = req.params;
  try {
    const followingPosts = await Post.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          message: { $regex: `#${hashtag}` },
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          createdAt: -1,
        },
      },
      {
        $limit: 10,
      },
    ]);
    if (!followingPosts) {
      res.status(204).json([]);
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(followingPosts);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

```
export const getHashtagPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const { hashtag } = req.params;
  try {
    const hashtagPosts = await Post.find({
      message: { $regex: `^#${hashtag}` },
    });
    if (!hashtagPosts) {
      res.status(204).json([]);
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(hashtagPosts);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

and If I run these code with "#l" this hashtag I will get this data

```
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #lol blah blah blah hellohellohellohello'})
({...someData, message: '#lol asdfff blah blah blah byebyebye'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff asdffasfdah blah blah #lol hello'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #l blah blah blah hello'})
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #lo blah blah blah hello'})
```

What I want, the result

```
({...someData, message: 'asdfff #l blah blah blah hello'})
```

I have no idea how can i get datas like that. thanks for reading my question

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
message: { $regex: /.*#l.*/, $options: 'i' { // if it is case insensitive add $options
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. but it didn't work for me. sadly still get the same data